# PHP: how can I convert jpeg to png and then zip (without making a copy)

Tags: php

So what I'm trying to do is:
- given an image url -> convert image to png
- zip resulting png

I have the following code which successfully does the conversion and zipping (I'm going to expand it later to test the extension to auto convert formats):

```
$file = "../assets/test.jpg";
$img = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
imagePng($img, "files/temp.png" );
$zip->addFile( "files/temp.png", "test.png" );
```

What I want to know is, is it possible to do this without creating a copy of image before it's zipped

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [`ZipArchive::addFromString()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addfromstring.php).

```
$file = "../assets/test.jpg";

// capture output into the internal buffer
ob_start();

$img = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
imagepng($img);

// get contents from the buffer
$contents = ob_get_clean();

$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open('archive.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE);

// and put them in the zip file...
$zip->addFromString('name_in_the_zip.png', $contents);
```